# SQL Query: Combine multiple rows [using a CASE WHEN x IN (1,2,3...)] to one row

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I want to combine all rows of the same media_type value to one row.

Here is my query (slightly modified to keep private info private):

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN media_type IN ('1','3') THEN 'A'
    WHEN media_type IN ('2','4') THEN 'B'
    WHEN media_type IN ('5','21','22') THEN 'C'
    WHEN media_type IN ('7','8','23') THEN 'D'
    WHEN media_type IN ('9') THEN 'E'
END AS media_type,
SUM(imp) as imps,
SUM(seller_revenue) as seller_revenue,
SUM(seller_revenue) / SUM(imp)  as CPM

FROM
    table

WHERE 
    dd = '2016-01-19'

GROUP BY
    media_type

ORDER BY
    seller_revenue desc

LIMIT 100;
```

Current output (data changed for privacy):

```
media_type  imps    seller_revenue  cpm
A   2681524581  4636356  1.729
B   18152099106 22345234 1.231
A   113355218.6 635356   5.605
A   83881452.47 235623   2.809
A   27994649.23 235435   8.41
C   4924414.093 63456    12.886
D   522212.1487 3456     6.618
C   569451.3099 3456     6.069
B   821059.4315 2542     3.096
B   220102.1505 409.39   1.86
D   103231.5978 345      3.342
A   88757.39645 345      3.887
E   300261.0966 345      1.149
A   213622.291  345      1.615
B   118701.5504 245      2.064
D   211678.8321 145      0.685
B   57798.16514 63       1.09
E   47619.04762 56       1.176
C   44191.91919 35       0.792
B   140186.9159 15       0.107
A   4288.777698 6        1.399
```

Desired output (sorting is not important):

```
media_type  seller_revenue  imps    cpm_calc
B    22,348,508      18,153,456,955      1.23 
A    5,743,466       2,907,062,569       1.98 
C    66,947          5,538,057           12.09 
D    3,946           837,123             4.71 
E    401             347,880             1.15 
Grand Total 28163268.39 21067242584 1.33682746
```

Thank you!

Surprised I haven't found this asked before with an hour of searching, I wonder if it's not usually an issue?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE like this:

```
WITH media_type as (
    SELECT old,new from (values
        ('1', 'A'),('3', 'A'),
        ('2', 'B'),('4', 'B'),
        ('5', 'C'),('21','C'),('22','C'),
        ('7', 'D'),('8', 'D'),('23','D'),
        ('9', 'E')
    )media_type(old,new)
)
SELECT 
    media_type.new AS media_type,
    SUM(imp) as imps,
    SUM(seller_revenue) as seller_revenue,
    SUM(seller_revenue) / SUM(imp)  as CPM

FROM
    table
JOIN media_type on media_type.old = table.media_type
WHERE 
    dd = '2016-01-19'

GROUP BY
    table.media_type

ORDER BY
    seller_revenue desc

LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which SQL vendor you're using...

If you're using Oracle, I think you could use 
WM_CONCAT

For MySQL, you could use
GROUP_CONCAT

(Here's an example: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/ )

And SQL-Server has some wonky workarounds to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MySQL.
Using group_concat, I believe this works to concatenate strings.  I am looking to sum integers.

Comment: Sorry... I misunderstood your question, I thought the commas in your desired output were strings for some reason... I'm not sure why a regular SUM won't do the trick... Is it the "grand total" row that is actually the main issue here? And if so... The "CUBE" or "ROLLUP" functions may be what you're looking for.. unfortunally, they're very restricted when it comes to MySQL.

Comment: Nope, I'd be happy even without the Grand Total -- that's more of a "nice to have".  It seems that even though I am using, for example,...
CASE
    WHEN media_type IN ('1','3') THEN 'A',...
Then there will be one line for '1'... called A... and there will be a second line for '3'... also called 'A'.

I'm trying to get all 'A' on the same line, etc.

Comment: Hmmm... try putting the entire case statement in the group by clause, or alternativy, write a subquery with the case logic and then wrap it with a query that has the aggregate logic.  SQL engines execite the GROUP BY clause BEFORE they execute the SELECT clause, so at the time the engine runs the GROUP BY part the case statement doesn't even exist yet.